# "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" when calling Api Management from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have an Azure Logic App where I have added, through the Designer, an action to call an Azure Api Management (APIM) operation. As said, I used the Logic App Designer which guided me through the process of selecting the APIM operation.

Now, when the Logic App is executed, I get the following error when trying to call the APIM operation:

> BadRequest. Http request failed with status code 'TrustFailure' and
>   status message: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not
>   establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? I am a bit stuck here...

Comment: Did you resolve this? an alternative is to use the HTTP connector

Comment: Having the same issue when calling an external odata-service using the HTTP connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in contact with Microsoft (Azure support) on this and learned the following. Quote:

> I further talked to the product team and actually there is a
>   limitation in the API Management action.  The current API Management
>   action in logic app cannot handle custom domain.  The team will look
>   into supporting it in future.
>
> For now, the suggested workaround is to use Http+Swagger action
>   instead. Then you will be able to update the URI by yourself.

Just to make this clear: this applies if you try to call Api Management actions from Azure Logic Apps. If you have for example a web app and want to call an APIM action, then custom domains will work just fine.

Comment: Are you supposed to use an IP address instead of the custom domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a bug due to using a custom domain name with SSL certificate on your APIM environment. We've seen the Logic Apps fail on this.

I think the Logic App resolves to the "original/internal" url, but the certificate doesn't match this (because that's connected to your custom domain)

Comment: Learned from Azure support now that it really had with custom domain to do. I will write an answer below.

Comment: Are you supposed to use an IP address instead of the custom domain name?